# What is the shortcut key to show/hide tool buttons in PhpStorm?

Tags: phpstorm, phpstorm-2017.1, phpstorm-2016.1, phpstorm-2016.3, phpstorm-2017.2

I am unable to find the shortcut key for this button. And as I do not know the name of this button I cannot search for it.

[image: phpstorm button]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is your answer from official [docs](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/manipulating-the-tool-windows.html)

> Hiding all tool windows attached to the same tool window bar
>
> Do one of the following:
>
> Press and hold the Alt (for Windows and Linux users) or ⌘ (for macOS users) key, and click hide on the title bar of any of the tool
> windows attached to the corresponding tool window bar.
>
> Choose Window | Active Tool Window | Hide Side Tool Windows in the main menu. This command hides all the tool windows attached to same
> tool window bar as the active tool window or the last of the active
> tool windows.

I find that double tapping `Alt` key does the trick for me.

Answer (score 3):

There is no shortcut by default, but you can go to Settings and type "tool buttons" into the search bar. Then you can assign a keystroke to "Tool Buttons" feature.

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

Maybe is `Ctrl+Tab`

Check [this](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/keyboard-shortcuts-you-cannot-miss.html). In the link you can read :

> Switch between the tool windows and files opened in the
>   editor.   Ctrl+Tab